# How to up sample dates in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to up-sampling the dates with a mean between the previous and the next one of the same ID. I cannot apply the rolling to a datetime type. Also the interpolation doesn't work as I am expecting, in fact it duplicates the previous date and I cannot do the mean. So I used a for cycle to do this, but it stops at first cycle. Can you solve this problem? Or do you know an alternative and faster way?

Here the code I wrote to build the dataframe:

```
Values = [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4, 4.6, 3.3, 5.3, 3.8 ,2.6, 2.4, 5.9, 4.9, 5.1, 5.1, 5.4, 2.7,4.9, 4.7, 5.5]
ID = [2002070, 2002070,2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2003010,2003010,2003010]
date = ['2005-12-07', '2008-05-14', '2008-10-27', '2009-04-20', '2012-03-01', '2013-11-28','2012-08-13', '2011-07-27', '2011-11-02', '2012-06-29', '2014-02-13', '2014-06-16', '2014-09-12','2011-01-10', '2011-04-05', '2012-11-02', '2013-02-07', '2013-08-15', '2013-11-15', '2014-01-23']
date=pd.to_datetime(date)
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'Values': Values, 'Date': date})

         ID  Values       Date
0   2002070     4.5 2005-12-07
1   2002070     4.2 2008-05-14
2   2002070     3.7 2008-10-27
3   2002070     4.8 2009-04-20
4   2002070     4.4 2012-03-01
5   2002070     4.6 2013-11-28
6   2002070     3.3 2012-08-13
7   2002070     5.3 2011-07-27
8   2002070     3.8 2011-11-02
9   2002740     2.6 2012-06-29
10  2002740     2.4 2014-02-13
11  2002740     5.9 2014-06-16
12  2002740     4.9 2014-09-12
13  2002740     5.1 2011-01-10
14  2002740     5.1 2011-04-05
15  2002740     5.4 2012-11-02
16  2002740     2.7 2013-02-07
17  2003010     4.9 2013-08-15
18  2003010     4.7 2013-11-15
19  2003010     5.5 2014-01-23
```

Below the mean calculation for the Values column. As you can see I obtain a NaT for the dates that I would like to substitute with the mean of the previous and the next date for the same ID

```
df1 = pd.concat(
    [
        df.groupby('ID')['Values'].rolling(2).mean()
            .dropna().reset_index('ID'),
        df
    ], sort=True
).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

         Date       ID  Values
0  2005-12-07  2002070    4.50
1         NaT  2002070    4.35
2  2008-05-14  2002070    4.20
3  2008-10-27  2002070    3.70
4         NaT  2002070    3.95
5  2009-04-20  2002070    4.80
6         NaT  2002070    4.25
7  2012-03-01  2002070    4.40
8         NaT  2002070    4.60
9  2013-11-28  2002070    4.60
10        NaT  2002070    4.50
11 2012-08-13  2002070    3.30
12        NaT  2002070    3.95
13 2011-07-27  2002070    5.30
14        NaT  2002070    4.30
15 2011-11-02  2002070    3.80
16        NaT  2002070    4.55
17 2012-06-29  2002740    2.60
18 2014-02-13  2002740    2.40
19        NaT  2002740    2.50
20 2014-06-16  2002740    5.90
21        NaT  2002740    4.15
22        NaT  2002740    5.40
23 2014-09-12  2002740    4.90
24        NaT  2002740    5.00
25 2011-01-10  2002740    5.10
26        NaT  2002740    5.10
27 2011-04-05  2002740    5.10
28        NaT  2002740    5.25
29 2012-11-02  2002740    5.40
30        NaT  2002740    4.05
31 2013-02-07  2002740    2.70
32 2013-08-15  2003010    4.90
33        NaT  2003010    4.80
34 2013-11-15  2003010    4.70
35        NaT  2003010    5.10
36 2014-01-23  2003010    5.50
```

The next code is used to calculate the mean of the date on df (not df1), then I will concatenate the mean series with df. But it doesn't work.

```
mean = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(df)), name='mid', index=df.index)
val=[0,0]
previous = next_ = None
l = len(df)
for index, obj in enumerate(df):
    if obj == 'Date':
        if index > 0:
            previous = df[obj][index - 1]
            
            
        if index < (l - 1):
            next_ = df[obj][index + 1]
            
        val=[previous, next_]
        mean[index] = (np.array(val, dtype='datetime64[s]').view('i8').mean().astype('datetime64[s]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving the problem is to take the average in the rolling function, which is a requirement, and make it a separate data frame. Add a cumulative count in ID units to the original and new data frame, respectively.
Combine them vertically and order them by ID and Flg.

```
df['flg'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Values'].rolling(2).mean().reset_index()
df1.drop('level_1', inplace=True, axis=1)
df1.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
df1['flg'] = df1.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0)
df2.sort_values(['ID','flg'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
df2.drop('flg', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True)
ID  Values  Date
0   2002070 4.50    2005-12-07
1   2002070 4.35    NaT
2   2002070 4.20    2008-05-14
3   2002070 3.95    NaT
4   2002070 3.70    2008-10-27
5   2002070 4.25    NaT
6   2002070 4.80    2009-04-20
7   2002070 4.60    NaT
8   2002070 4.40    2012-03-01
9   2002070 4.50    NaT
10  2002070 4.60    2013-11-28
11  2002070 3.95    NaT
12  2002070 3.30    2012-08-13
13  2002070 4.30    NaT
14  2002070 5.30    2011-07-27
15  2002070 4.55    NaT
16  2002070 3.80    2011-11-02
17  2002740 2.60    2012-06-29
18  2002740 2.50    NaT
19  2002740 2.40    2014-02-13
20  2002740 4.15    NaT
21  2002740 5.90    2014-06-16
22  2002740 5.40    NaT
23  2002740 4.90    2014-09-12
24  2002740 5.00    NaT
25  2002740 5.10    2011-01-10
26  2002740 5.10    NaT
27  2002740 5.10    2011-04-05
28  2002740 5.25    NaT
29  2002740 5.40    2012-11-02
30  2002740 4.05    NaT
31  2002740 2.70    2013-02-07
32  2003010 4.90    2013-08-15
33  2003010 4.80    NaT
34  2003010 4.70    2013-11-15
35  2003010 5.10    NaT
36  2003010 5.50    2014-01-23
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the *NaT* by the "median" dates between 2 valid ones, I would convert date to *int* and interpolate.

Add this column to you dataframe

```
import numpy as np
df['Date_'] = df['Date'].astype(np.int64)
```

Then on *df1*:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_'].interpolate()).dt.normalize()
df1.head(5)
```

```
 Date         Date_       ID  Values
0 2005-12-07  1.133914e+18  2002070    4.50
1 2007-02-24           NaN  2002070    4.35
2 2008-05-14  1.210723e+18  2002070    4.20
3 2008-10-27  1.225066e+18  2002070    3.70
4 2009-01-22           NaN  2002070    3.95
```

Comment: thank you. Actually my Date column is a Series so I have to write df['Date_']=df['Date'].values.astype(int) in order to convert the Series in np array and then to apply the astype(int). But this return strange dates as                                                  
 1970-01-01 should be  2005-12-07, 
 1970-01-01      should be  2007-02-24, 
 1969-12-31 should be   2008-05-14,
 1970-01-01      should be   2008-10-27. Do you know why?

Comment: this is the error I obtain without .values.astype(int) --> TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: I assume it comes from your integer format. As safer approach (not tested) would be: 1/ import numpy as np 2/ df['Date'].astype(np.int64)